# Failed to load info.plist bundle for Quickblox framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, quickblox

We are using pod of Quickblox framework in app and we are facing below problem.

```
Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/SandeepApple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/55985961-C1EC-4102-BF08-2FFD1EE5BDD0/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.JzPbI0/extracted/GigMates.app/Frameworks/Quickblox.framework
```

Comment: Have you figured this out? Im getting the same error. `#import <Quickblox/Quickblox.h>` doesn't help.

Comment: are you using pod

Comment: not using cocoapods

Answer (score 1):

You have in the Bridging-Header.h this line:

```
#import <Quickblox/Quickblox.h>
```

If you use pods, you need 3 pods:
pod 'QuickBlox'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'